# Importing csv file to google sheets using script

Tags: google-apps-script

i am faced with the below problem. I am going to be presented with a .csv file that will contain the following fields:

```
ItemID  Date    Source name Title   URL Created ItemSourceType
```

However i won't need all of the fields but i will need to import this into a pre-defined google sheets template, which looks like the below:

```
Date    Writer  Status  Geog/Area/Product   Source  Title   Note
```

Again not all of the columns will need to be populated, and so the final solution should look like this.

```
Date    Writer  Status  Geog/Area/Product   Source  Title   Note 
Today() NULL    NULL    Null                Site    Title-(hyperlinked with URL)   Null
```

i have put together the following code - some of this has been testing and trying to split out a CSV, and i've not yet attempted to add the hyperlinked field.

```
function addData() {
  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('138ZRbesgDkKHOROm4izD22oaXoanvsyJ'); // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 12;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process

  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('138ZRbesgDkKHOROm4izD22oaXoanvsyJ'); // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved
  var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('data.csv'); // latest report file
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1wBawJzQ3eAhyjCuetAFg7uUUrum6CDImBcVcxaZ9j84'); // data_sheet_id = id of spreadsheet that holds the data to be updated with new report data

  if ( fi.hasNext() ) { // proceed if "report.csv" file exists in the reports folder
    var file = fi.next();
    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); 
    for ( var i=1, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
  }


  function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ) {
    // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
    // then default to COMMA.
    strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

    // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
    var objPattern = new RegExp(
      (
        // Delimiters.
        "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

        // Quoted fields.
        "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

        // Standard fields.
        "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
      ),
      "gi"
    );

    // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
    // a default empty first row.
    var arrData = [[]];

    // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
    // matching groups.
    var arrMatches = null;

    // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
    // until we can no longer find a match.
    while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

      // Get the delimiter that was found.
      var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

      // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
      // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
      // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
      // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
      if (
        strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
        (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
        ){

          // Since we have reached a new row of data,
          // add an empty row to our data array.
          arrData.push( [] );

        }

      // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
      // let's check to see which kind of value we
      // captured (quoted or unquoted).
      if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

        // We found a quoted value. When we capture
        // this value, unescape any double quotes.
        var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
          new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
          "\""
        );

      } else {

        // We found a non-quoted value.
        var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

      }

      // Now that we have our value string, let's add
      // it to the data array.
      arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
    }

    // Return the parsed data.
    return( arrData );
  };


  // Fetch the range of cells A2:G3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows,8)//sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 8)

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var ItemID = row[0]
    var Date = row[1]
    var SourceName = row[2]
    var Title = row[3]
    var URL = row[4]
    var Created = row[5]
    var ItemSourceType = row[6]
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
  }

  var correctFormat = ItemID + ", " + Date + ", " + SourceName + ", " + Title + ", " + URL + ", " + Created + ", " + ItemSourceType;


  Logger.log(correctFormat) 
}
```

If anyone is able to help point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

The part of this that i am struggling with is using the Array to populate the spreadsheet with the fields in the correct order, I have put the array below.

```
  function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ) {
// Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
// then default to COMMA.
strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

// Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
var objPattern = new RegExp(
  (
    // Delimiters.
    "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

    // Quoted fields.
    "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

    // Standard fields.
    "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
  ),
  "gi"
);

// Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
// a default empty first row.
var arrData = [[]];

// Create an array to hold our individual pattern
// matching groups.
var arrMatches = null;

// Keep looping over the regular expression matches
// until we can no longer find a match.
while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

  // Get the delimiter that was found.
  var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

  // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
  // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
  // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
  // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
  if (
    strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
    (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }

  // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
  // let's check to see which kind of value we
  // captured (quoted or unquoted).
  if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

    // We found a quoted value. When we capture
    // this value, unescape any double quotes.
    var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
      new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
      "\""
    );

  } else {

    // We found a non-quoted value.
    var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

  }

  // Now that we have our value string, let's add
  // it to the data array.
  arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
}

// Return the parsed data.
return( arrData );
```

};

Comment: What's your specific question? All I see is a "this is what I'm doing" statement.

Comment: basically the CSV i receive is not in the correct layout, and i need to manipulate the fields upon import to put them into the correct place within the google spreadsheet that is currently used. so the issue i have isn't extracting the data and putting it into a google sheet, it is importing certain fields from the csv into the correct place.

Comment: the code you share here already demonstrates how to access elements of an array via bracket notation. You also identify the header order you want to obtain, and the as-received data ordering.  So what is the specific issue you are having with creating the array to write that has the desired order?

Comment: The array doesn't appear to be moving the fields to the correct place when i am writing the data, which is where the problem is currently.

Comment: Is this code your exact Apps Script code? It would help everyone to apply the proper formatting / indentation levels (you can highlight your Apps Script **.gs** file and press `Tab` to auto-indent it based on its syntax), as that can help resolve logic errors from missing semicolons, braces, brackets, and parentheses. It appears that your script (as posted in this question) has a function definition in the middle of it, and also that it first writes the csv data as-is, then re-reads it and attempts to re-write it. Why not just `map` the csv `Array` to the desired output format before writing?

Comment: it is indeed, and i am new to the google scripts coding, and appreciate the helpful tip.That makes sense, are you able to help in anyway? as i think that would resolve my issue straight away.

Comment: part of the process of asking a good question is distilling from your actual project code to a MCVE, essentially removing everything that is unrelated to the issue at hand. Please use this opportunity to at least edit your script to have a more conventional layout of functions, organized and meaningful indentation levels, and so on. This will help not only you, but anyone who wishes to help.

Comment: I have modified the above, and formatted the code correctly, i might be able to get the assistance i need now with getting the Array to write the data into the correct columns recursively.

Comment: is your issue with your function, or with  the function you found which converts a csv-formatted string into an array of that string's data? If the helper function is properly converting a csv-formatted string into the corresponding array representation, then I do not believe it is the source of your hardship, and it can actually be omitted from your question.

Answer (score 8):

It seems like this site (https://ctrlq.org/code/20279-import-csv-into-google-spreadsheet) does include several ways to import a CSV into a google spreadsheet.

For instance for importing from google drive you can do:

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("data.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

After that you will need to filter the data you want, but i guess it is easier to do that once you have imported the data from the csv.