# Regex to match new line in windows generated CSV

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, export-to-csv, sqlcmd

I am writing an Apps Script based on the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326047/importing-csv-file-to-google-sheets-using-script).

The regex that is used equates to the below
`(\,|\r?\n|\r|^)(?:"([^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*)"|([^"\,\r\n]*)`.

I am trying use the above Regex to detect end of line in a CSV generated by sqlcmd in Windows environment.

The regex however doesn't detect new line.

I am very new to regex hence my understanding is limited.

Are there any differences in line breaks in different environments?

If so how could the above regex be modified to cater for the different environments?